# How to send a Message Delivery Status with fail status using MailKit

Tags: smtp, mailkit

We have a dovecot/postfix mail server which we use for automation purposes through IMAP and SMTP protocols.

There are situations that the system processes the email message but there is something wrong with the message and the system will exclude the message from the pipeline.

As the email messages are coming in from different sources, the system needs to inform the sender about the failure, and again for automation purposes, the other party expects a Message Delivery Status message with status fail.

We use MailKit for handling the messages and I had been trying to figure out how I can send such a message using MailKit in C#, but I have not been successful.

A simplified version of the code I have is as following:

```cs
// Prepares smtpClient

MultipartReport multipartReport = new MultipartReport("delivery-status")
{
    new TextPart {Content = new MimeContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("The message contains malformed data")))},
    
    new MessageDeliveryStatus {StatusGroups = {new HeaderList {new Header("Action", "failed")}}}
};

MimeMessage  message = new MimeMessage
{
    Body = multipartReport,
    
    From = { new MailboxAddress("Webmaster", "webmaster@our.domain")},
    
    To = { new MailboxAddress("User", "user@origin.domain")},
    
    Subject = "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)",
    
    InReplyTo = "message id of the received message"
};

smtpClient.Send(mimeMessage);
```

**Update:**
With the suggested modification by @jstedfast now the code generates the following message:

```
From: Webmaster <webmaster@ourdomain.com>
Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2021 23:50:56 +0100
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
Message-Id: <GII2AYZOWCU4.AXDWNKVKJ4XD3@ourdomain.com>
To: First Last <someone@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; boundary="=-HnKieASbitf0LQ3XjF16Mw==";
    report-type=delivery-status

--=-HnKieASbitf0LQ3XjF16Mw==
Content-Type: text/plain

Attachment not allowed
--=-HnKieASbitf0LQ3XjF16Mw==
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns;mail.ourdomain.com

Final-Recipient: rfc822;user@ourdomain.com
Action: failed
Status: 550 5.7.1


--=-HnKieASbitf0LQ3XjF16Mw==--
```

What happens after sending the message is that, it is received and displayed as a regular email message in the original sender's mailbox.

**Update 2:**

If it helps, I use `Postfix` as the SMTP server and it seems to me that, it might be `Postfix` that modifies the mime message and converts it to a regular text mime message.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what isn't working, it's hard to know what to suggest.

That said, a quick look at the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464) reveals that the "Action" header is part of the `per-recipient-fields` which is an optional *second* group of status headers.

The first grouping of header fields is the `per-message-fields` which should include fields like:

```
per-message-fields =
    [ original-envelope-id-field CRLF ]
    reporting-mta-field CRLF
    [ dsn-gateway-field CRLF ]
    [ received-from-mta-field CRLF ]
    [ arrival-date-field CRLF ]
    *( extension-field CRLF )
```

The `per-recipient-fields` are defined as:

```
per-recipient-fields =
    [ original-recipient-field CRLF ]
    final-recipient-field CRLF
    action-field CRLF
    status-field CRLF
    [ remote-mta-field CRLF ]
    [ diagnostic-code-field CRLF ]
    [ last-attempt-date-field CRLF ]
    [ final-log-id-field CRLF ]
    [ will-retry-until-field CRLF ]
    *( extension-field CRLF )
```

This means, at a minimum, you'd need to change the way you construct the `MessageDeliveryStatus` part to something more like the following:

```
new MessageDeliveryStatus {
    StatusGroups = {
        new HeaderList {
            new Header("Reporting-MTA", "dns;<dns name of the MTA>")
        },
        new HeaderList {
            new Header("Final-Recipient", "rfc822;<address of recipient>",
            new Header("Action", "failed"),
            new Header("Status", "5.something")
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to choose a status code from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463

Comment: Thanks @jstedfast you are the most helpful as always. I will give it a try and get back to you soon. :)

Comment: jstedfast, I'm having trouble extracting the Reporting-MTA (dns name of the MTA) and Final-Recipient (address of recipient) values from the MimeMessage data. Can you please help me with some code samples? I highly appreciate it.

Comment: I mean for the final recipient part, is it TO, CC and BCC email addresses or is there any other value that I need to use?

Comment: The Reporting-MTA field should just be a hard-coded value for your mail server. The Final-Recipient address should be the address that your software is responding for. It should be only 1. Or if it is running as part of a multi-user system, then you'd need to send multiple delivery-status messages (one per recipient that your server is hosting).

Comment: jstedfast I have updated my question with some results. Would you please take a look again?